# What is the probability that, within a sequence of 20 shots, the player can score five baskets in a row?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Task description:

[image]

Hellow everyone, i have that task. And i have a slight problems with solving it on wolfram calculatior, i need to find a probability for it and investigate a problem in some depth using random numbers and Monte Carlo simulation in excel.

I want to use that formula.

Formulas:

[image]

Where $m = 5$, $p = 0.75$, $n = 20$.

I would appreciate any advice on how to analytically solve this problem in excel, with using vba excel code, if it necesary , i.e. expressing that answer in excel can me help simulate problem with different inputs.

Thank you!

Comment: It’s not clear to me from the quoted question whether it’s asking about *exactly* 5 shots in a row or *at least* 5. From the formula you’ve pasted in, it looks like you’re interpreting it as the latter, but you should make that clear in your question.

Comment: Assuming you meant "at least $5$" then I'd say it was easier to do the compliment (probability that the longest string is $4$ or fewer).  That one you can do recursively, keeping track of "good" strings that end with exactly $n$ hits in a row (for $n\in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$)

Comment: Lets it will be at least five shots, so which formula i need to use to find that probability?

Comment: See http://www.askamathematician.com/2010/07/q-whats-the-chance-of-getting-a-run-of-k-successes-in-n-bernoulli-trials-why-use-approximations-when-the-exact-answer-is-known/

Comment: Are this for series in the row ? Because i dont know how to apply that huge formula to excel, may be the formula which i posted must be better?